# Strange behaviour with Text in Rectangle

Tags: qt, text, qml

I have a problem with a Rectangle that should contain Text. Text should be in the Rectangle defined but it goes beyond it.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle
    {
        id:listRest
        width: parent.width/2.7
        height: parent.height/2.5
        color: "dimgray"
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.topMargin: Math.round(parent.height)/12
        anchors.margins: Math.round(parent.width)/50

        Text {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: qsTr("QML (Qt Modeling Language) is a user interface markup language. It is a declarative language for designing user interface–centric applications.")
        }
    } 
}
```

How can I get Text to be only in Rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `Text` will display its content as it is. So, if the text doesn't contain enough new line and it's too long, the text will be display outside the rectangle.

Use `wrapMode: Text.WordWrap`to wrap the text in the bounds of the rectangle and 
`elide: Text.ElideRight` to elide the text if it's too long to fit in the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

[Using a wrapMode (a max width)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345164/qml-text-wrap-max-width)

Or maybe a simple solution that is not elegant, but work. Use "\n" for a new line when is it possible without other over-complicated methods if is just only for a simple small text line.